# Is the pressure the same if I heat to the same temperature different closed containers with distinct ratios of water to air?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

Say I have 3 closed containers of 1L each. By volume, the 1st one is 50/50 air and water, the 2nd is 20% water and 80% air, and the third is 80% water and 20% air. If I heat all of them to the same temperature of 120 C. Are they all under the same internal pressure?

EDIT: They all start at atmosphere pressure (1 atm) and room temperature (20 C) before I close the lid and start heating them.

Comment: Do they all have the same mass? Or do they all have the same number of particles?

Comment: They all start at regular atmosphere pressure before I heat them.

Comment: Aside from the effect of changing the amount of liquid water as a result of different amounts of evaporation and different amounts of volume change from thermal expansion, the three pressures will be about the same.

Answer (score 1):

No in general they're not. When you start the experiment you have liquid water. The total number of particles is not the same in the three different containers. If you have to consider the values given in your question , than you basically have three pressure cookers. Even the container containing less water, about 200 g, given that you have 1 l room and stop heating at 120 °C,** provides enough molecules to attain the vapour P. It will be about 2 atm, you may look at the water PT diagram.

(**PV = nRT gives 358 atm)

Let us assume the volume of the containers be much larger and/or the amount of water much less. Then consider that the molecular weight (averaged) of air is almost twice that of water and especially that air in the initial conditions is hundreds time less dense than water. You can then simplify your calculations or at least your reasoning by assuming that your system contains just water, in terms of number of moles (number of particles) and specific heat.

Answer (score 0):

The containers all start at the same pressure $P_0$, volume $V_0$ and temperature $T_0$. They each consist of two gas species, consisting of a number of particles $N_1$ and $N_2$. These exert partial pressures $P_1$ and $P_2$. By Dalton's law of partial pressures, the total pressure in the container is given by

$$P = P_1+P_2$$

which, when we apply the ideal gas law, becomes

$$P = \frac{N_1kT}{V_0}+\frac{N_2kT}{V_0} = (N_1+N_2)\frac{kT}{V_0}$$

which means that the total pressure in the container as a function of temperature depends only on the total number of particles $N=N_1+N_2$ in the container. Since each gas mixture is at the same temperature, volume, and pressure, we can see that

$$N = \frac{P_0V_0}{kT_0}$$

which is the same in each case. Therefore, the pressure in each container is the same as a function of temperature.

Comment: But we can see that the different containers start out with different number of molecules, so the pressures must at the end must also be different. You say that the the containers start out with similar conditions, but that is not true, since there are different mixes of fluids in different phases.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a pressure cooker.

Probably_someone's answer is right if all water evaporates or boils and you just have a mix of two gases. As he said, pressure will depend on the amount of gas inside of the container.

However, as long as there is liquid water in the container, it will stop boiling when pressure in the container reaches [its vapour pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapour_pressure_of_water) at its temperature.

According to this [steam pressure calculator](http://www.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/steam-table-temperature.html) vapour pressure at 120ºC is 198.665 kPa (about two atmospheres) and that will be the pressure in the container at 120ºC as long as some water remains in it. Since if the container originally had 20%, 50% or 80% of water, some water will remain in liquid state, and therefore in the conditions of the question, the container will be at this pressure.

Only if the container contained very little water (let's say less than 1/20 of the container) or if you heat it more than 120ºC, all water will be converted to steam and probably_someone's answer will apply. Please notice that in this "dry" situation pressure will be lower.

Comment: What class/subject do you need to take to cover this kind of material? Thanks!

Comment: Three decades ago in Catalonia, most of this was taught in high school courses for 15-16 year old students, in classes of physics and chemistry. At more advanced level I suppose changes of phase are covered in physical chemistry or thermodynamics classes.

Comment: Would the same amount of water be converted to gas in all cases?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The same pressure will be reached. If there is a different volume of water, only the remaining of the container can be filled with gas. The more water, the less available space, the less steam.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to do the calculation for 20% water and 80% air, and you can then repeat the calculations for the other mixtures.  We will neglect the initial amount of water vapor in the air at 20 C.  So there are 200 cc of liquid water and 0.8 l of air.  The specific volume of liquid water at 20 C is 1.002 cc/gm, so the mass of water is 199.6 gm and the number of moles of air is determined from the ideal gas law as [(0.9869)(0.8)]/[(0.0821)(293)]=0.0328 moles = 0.952 gm.

From the steam tables, at 120 C, the equilibrium vapor pressure of water vapor is 1.985 bars, the specific volume of liquid water is 1.060 cc/gm and the specific volume of water vapor is 892 cc/gm.  So, if x represents the number of grams of water vapor in the gas space, we have (199.6-x) grams of water in the liquid space.  So,we have, $$892x+1.060(199.6-x)=1000$$This gives 0.885 gm of water in the gas phase and 199.6-0.885=198.7 gm of liquid water.  So the volume of liquid water at 120 C will be  (198.7)(1.060)=211 cc and the volume of gas will be 1000-211=789 cc.  Neglecting any air dissolved in the water, the partial pressure of the air in the gas space will be $[(1.0)(800)(273+120)]/[(789)(293)]=1.36\ bars$. So the total pressure in the container will be 1.985+1.36 = 3.35 bars.

Comment: Does gm stand for grams?

Comment: How can the pressure be higher than 1.985 bars at 120 C if that is the equilibrium vapor pressure of water vapor at that temp?

Comment: The partial pressure of the air in the container is not zero (you said that there is air in the container, right?).  In this example, the partial pressure of the air is 1.32 bars at 120 C.  If there were no air in the container (just pure water), the pressure would be 1.985 bars.

Comment: Ok, so the pressure in the container IS affected by the ratio of water to air, and more air would mean higher pressure?

Comment: Why don't you work out the other two cases using the template that I provided and see what you get.? I think you will find that the effect of the water to air ratio is very inconsequential for most of the range of possible ratios.  Only when there is extremely little water to start with or extremely little air to start with will there be a considerable difference.

Comment: I'm confused how you calculated the partial pressure of the air in the gas space in the last 3 sentences. I'm unsure what the 1.0, 800 and 293 are coming from and what equation is being used.

Comment: The equation I used was $$\frac{p_2V_2}{T_2}=\frac{p_1V_1}{T_1}$$where the subscript 1 refers to the initial state at 20 C (293 K) and the subscript 2 refers to the final state at 120 C (393 K).  This equation is derived directly from the ideal gas law, assuming that the number of moles of air in the head space does not change.  The 800 cc is the initial volume of the head space, and the 789 cc is the final volume of the head space.  The 1.0 is the initial pressure of 1 bar.

Comment: Incidentally, there was an arithmetic error in my application of the above equation in my original post which have corrected.  The correct partial pressure of the air in the final state is 1.36 bars.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, the 0.885 gm of water is the amount of water that has evaporated into the head space, assuming that the initial amount of water vapor in the head space at 20 C was negligible.  Since the initial amount of liquid water was 199.6 gm, the final amount of liquid water was 198.7 gm.  Since the specific volume of the liquid water at 120 C  is 1.06 cm^3/gm, its new volume will be 211 cc.  That will leave 1000-211 = 789 cc of heat space at 120 C.

Comment: thank you for all the help. When I play with the water/air ratios, I do get different values ranging somewhere between 3 - 5 atms. That seems pretty significant to me. Were you expecting something different?

Comment: For cases where the water doesn't all evaporate, or where there is not enough water present such that it would expand to a volume greater than 1 liter under unconstrained circumstances, I would expect the final pressure to be close to the calculated value of 3.35 bars.

Comment: Hi Chester, I followed the example with 90% water and it almost reached 5 atm pressure. Do you believe this is an error on my end or do the results make sense to you?

Comment: I believe that your answer is correct. The thermal expansion of the liquid water would reduce the head space considerably, and compress the air to less than half its original volume. The temperature rise of the air would raise the air partial pressure still more. Is that not what your calculations show?